# Apache POI: Cell / Row Style setting does not work

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a workbook with several Sheets containing data.

Requirements:

1) top row bold
2) all cells top and left aligned
3) Column size fits to **top row cell value**

I use the following code. It does not throw an error or exception, the File is filled successfully. But the style is not applied. I think I have missed something:

```
      ... // fill Excel ..

      if (sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows() > 0) {

        CellStyle topRowStyle = wb.createCellStyle();   // makes top row bold
        Font topRowFont = wb.createFont();              
        topRowFont.setBold(true);
        topRowStyle.setFont(topRowFont);
        sheet.getRow(0).setRowStyle(topRowStyle);

        CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();         // creates general sheet style
        Font font= wb.createFont();                     
        font.setFontHeightInPoints((short)10);
        font.setFontName("Arial");
        style.setFont(font);
        style.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_LEFT);
        style.setAlignment(CellStyle.VERTICAL_TOP);

        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();       
            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
              Row row = rowIterator.next();
              row.setRowStyle(style);
              int columnIndex = cell.getColumnIndex();              
            }
        }

           // continue with other stuff
```

In this code I tried to implement 1) and 2).
But has anyone an idea on how to solve 3)? I earlier worked with

```
sheet.autoSizeColumn(columnIndex);
```

But this just autofits the columns according to the longest (by character count) value.

Thank you!

Comment: Populate the first row, auto-size the columns, then populate the other rows?

Comment: In addition to @Gagravarr: Your row style is applied. You will see that if you put a value into a empty cell in any of the rows directly in Excel's GUI. Excel will then using the row style. But apache poi will not applying the row style automatically if you are creating a cell in that row. There you must do that yourself. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42081288/is-there-any-way-to-know-that-the-cellstyle-is-already-present-in-workbookto-re/42163746#42163746. There I have provided a method `public CellStyle getPreferredCellStyle(Cell cell)` for this.