# Merging Cells Vertically and Inserting Data Into The Cell

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

My question is I have 4 values. I need to represent them in a single cell.

I need to merge the cells vertically (columns) and present the four values one below the other (top to bottom) having line feeds between in that merged cell.

I am able to merge the cells vertically but unable to present the four values in a single cell.

```
CellRangeAddress cellRangeAddress = new CellRangeAddress(2,5,5,5);
sheet.addMergedRegion(cellRangeAddress);
```

Comment: concatenate them together use & or concatenate...

Comment: Thanks solar Mike for the Reply. can you Please Elaborate Bit Further. if I use Normal Concatenation I am getting Four Values in a Single Line in the Cell  but I want them In Sparate Line one by one Order

Comment: If you want 4 values in a single cell but on separate lines then you need to enter "hard" returns...

Comment: "No Idea How to Attach Screen Shot in Comment": Not in a comment but in the question. But it is clear now. So no screen shot needed.

Comment: Solar can you please Explain  hard Returns . With Code Example

Comment: @veera-venkatesh It is basically a hard-coded line break. In VBA you can use `& Chr(10)` to concatenate the line break to your string where you want the line to break

Comment: @axel-richter Please post a full-fledged answer to this question. Your solution is the good one, but doesn't really have its place in the comment section ;)

Comment: @veera-venkatesh turns out I misread your post : for apache-poi, you can use `"\n"` as follow `"something \n [this part will be displayed on a new line]"` to add a linebreak within a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The merged cell region orients them self on the first cell in that region. That means cell style as well as cell value. So the need is at first setting the cell style of first cell to wrap text. Then we need concatenating all cell values together into first cell's cell value delimited by "\n", the line feed. Then we can merging the cells.

Example:

SAMPLE.xlsx:
[image]

Code:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.util.LocaleUtil;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.Locale;

class ExcelConcatenateAndMerge {

 private static void concatenateAndMerge(
  Sheet sheet, CellRangeAddress cellRangeAddress, DataFormatter formatter, FormulaEvaluator evaluator, CellStyle cellStyle) {

  Row row = null;
  Cell cell = null;
  Cell firstCell = null;
  String cellValue = "";
  boolean first = true;
  for (CellAddress cellAddress : cellRangeAddress) {
   row = sheet.getRow(cellAddress.getRow());
   if (first) {
    if (row == null) row = sheet.createRow(cellAddress.getRow());
    firstCell = row.getCell(cellAddress.getColumn());
    if (firstCell == null) firstCell = row.createCell(cellAddress.getColumn());
    firstCell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
    cellValue = formatter.formatCellValue(firstCell, evaluator);
    first = false;
   } else {
    if (row != null) {
     cell = row.getCell(cellAddress.getColumn());
     if (cell != null) {
      cellValue += "\n" + formatter.formatCellValue(cell, evaluator);
     } else cellValue += "\n" + "";
    } else cellValue += "\n" + "";
   }
  }

  firstCell.setCellValue(cellValue);

  sheet.addMergedRegion(cellRangeAddress);

 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook wb  = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("SAMPLE.xlsx"));

  Locale locale = new Locale("en", "US");
  LocaleUtil.setUserLocale(locale);
  DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
  FormulaEvaluator evaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
  CellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
  cellStyle.setWrapText(true);

  Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
  CellRangeAddress cellRangeAddress = new CellRangeAddress(2,5,5,5);

  concatenateAndMerge(sheet, cellRangeAddress, formatter, evaluator, cellStyle);

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("SAMPLENEW.xlsx");
  wb.write(out);
  out.close();
  wb.close();

 }
}
```

SAMPLENEW.xlsx:
[image]

My method `concatenateAndMerge` uses `DataFormatter` because the source cells content might be not simply text but date or other numbers. Since the merged cells content needs to be a concatenated string, the different content of the previous single cells should be present in that concatenated string as shown before in the single cells. That's why the `DataFormatter`. And my method uses `FormulaEvaluator` because the  source cells content might contain formulas too.

Comment: Thanks alot  Axel Richter for the Answer .My Problem resolved but can you please Explain why you are  Using DataFormatter,FormulaEvaluator  in our code and How to auto size the Columns

Comment: @veera venkatesh: See my supplements in the answer. But "How to auto size the Columns"? What columns shall be autosized? And what about simply using [Sheet.autoSizeColumn](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#autoSizeColumn-int-boolean-)?

Comment: ok Axel .I figureOut My Problem by seeing The Link you have Provided , By Default MergeCells are Ignored for Autosizecolumn .we need to pass true Argument for the Method sheet.autosizeColumn(columnIndex,true).

Answer (score -1):

If using VBA directly in excel is a viable alternative, you can write a macro to do this task. The macro will be saved within the actual excel file.

When Excel merges cells, it only keeps the value of the first cell, so before you make those cells merge, concatenate their value in the format you want. To add a line-break to your value, concatenate `Chr(10)` where you want a new line.

Keep in mind that if you format numeric cells that way, the cell value will become a string and therefore can't be used anymore as a number in formulas.

The following code will do what you want* :

```
Dim finalValue As String
For Each c In Selection
    finalValue = finalValue & IIf((Len(finalValue) > 0) And (Len(c.Text) > 0), Chr(10), Empty) & c.Text
Next c

Selection.Clear
Selection.Merge
Selection.Value = finalValue
```

---

*note : I made the code with a selection in case you need to perform this task on a variable cell number, but it will work on any `Range` object

also note that an empty cell will not make an empty line unless you remove the `And (Len(c.Text) > 0)` condition in `IIf`. But by doing this, merging a selection with already merged cells will create as many empty lines as `[the size of the merged cell] - 1`

Comment: Why do you think this question is related to `VBA`? It is  clearly tagged `java` and `apache poi`.

Comment: `If using VBA directly in excel is a viable alternative` The answer is clearly stating that the proposed solution here is an alternative.